# Best pump for hot milk (Self priming)

Tags: design, pumps

I am currently in the process of building a machine that can make tea(in a saucepan). I have almost finalized everything, but am having trouble selecting what pump to use. I read the following [question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25337/best-affordable-food-grade-hot-water-pump) but could not find an answer for my question. I understand this might be considered a shopping question, but I am completely lost and have no clue of where to even start finding something that meets all my requirement - or if such a pump even exists.

**Requirements for the pump:**

- Food grade
- A flow rate of >=1000ml/minute (tea will be around 500 to 1000ml)
- Needs to be DC
- I will need two pumps. One to pump milk out of my refrigeration system and into my saucepan (Milk will be at 4°C).The second to pump hot tea(at 100°C) from my saucepan into a cup. Therefore, I need the pump to be self priming and be able to run dry and suck the liquid from a height of around 100 cm. It also needs to be able to safely pump 100°C liquids.

At first I thought of buying a peristaltic pump, however most DC run peristaltic pumps I found had too slow of a flow rate and the ones that were adequate were too expensive. I found [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003882171547.html?src=google&src=google&albch=shopping&acnt=708-803-3821&slnk=&plac=&mtctp=&albbt=Google_7_shopping&albagn=888888&isSmbAutoCall=false&needSmbHouyi=false&albcp=19108228023&albag=&trgt=&crea=en1005003882171547&netw=x&device=c&albpg=&albpd=en1005003882171547&gad_source=1&aff_fcid=4b56f1105b09470abf5a8d7fbeae3efc-1702860380752-04035-UneMJZVf&aff_fsk=UneMJZVf&aff_platform=aaf&sk=UneMJZVf&aff_trace_key=4b56f1105b09470abf5a8d7fbeae3efc-1702860380752-04035-UneMJZVf&terminal_id=5e8fdbd5fa0645ae8d60e87ebd13792c&afSmartRedirect=y) Diaphragm Pump on Ali express but could not find a datasheet, so I have no idea if it can be run dry or can even handle hot liquids.

Comment: `tea will be around 500 to 1000ml` ... are you certain? ... that's a lot of milk

Comment: I wouldn't drink any liquid that came into contact with a pump from Ali Express

Comment: So check out some of the fancy coffee machines - have pumps for coffee (hot) and milk (cold). Asking for "best" is opinion.

Comment: Oh and "self priming"? just put the pump lower than the tank of milk - gravity does the rest.

Comment: @jsotola yes it will be in that range since i will usually be making more than one cup of tea.

Comment: @SolarMike  Oh i didn't think of that! that would work for the milk but I would still need suction to pull tea from the saucepan

Comment: For milk, I think using a vacuum or a peristaltic pump are the only realistic options. Otherwise you will need to be able to easily clean every crevice inside the pump.